# how to add uiview in uiscrollview iphone/ipad

Tags: iphone, uiview, uiscrollview, addsubview

I want to add a custom uiview in my viewcontroller scroll view. and i am using below code but it not working. and not adding my viewThumbnail in scrollview.
my viewThumbnail contains a imageview.

```
for (int i=0; i<10; i++) {

        viewThumbnail *objTemp =[[viewThumbnail alloc] init];
        objTemp.frame = CGRectMake(i*165, 0, 126, 161);
        [self.scrlViewRecent addSubview:objTemp];

    }
[scrlViewRecent setContentSize:CGSizeMake((161 + 10)*10, 180)];
```

and if i use below code then it added blank view instead of viewThumbnail object

```
viewThumbnail *headContentView = [[viewThumbnail alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(i*161 + (i*10), 0, 161, 140)];
        [headContentView setBackgroundColor:[UIColor brownColor]];
        [self.scrlViewRecent addSubview:headContentView];
```

So please suggest me where i am doing wrong.
Thx

Comment: have you increased size of content of scrollview?

Comment: what exactly happen with your code? as i can't find any image in your iewThumbnail controller

Comment: ViewThumbnail have a imageview and imageview contain a static image.

Answer (score -1):

You are calling different `init` methods, make sure your setup code for the `viewThumbnail` actually gets called. Not sure if `self.scrlViewRecent` is the correct view to add to (lacking context here).

Also some observations:

- Class names should start with uppercase letter (`ViewThumbnail`)
- `scrlViewRecent` saves 2 characters out of 16 but makes it hard to read
- Your loop is most probably lacking
  your `viewThumbnail` objects. Make
  sure you release them somewhen.

Comment: Thanks for reply. but i have added uiimageview on viewThumbnail using ib. but it is not visible in scrollview.

Comment: Maybe your nib is not loaded at all, not every init method loads the nib!